# Flow to add column data to a newly created folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, connected-web-parts

I have made a flow that creates a folder in a document library called "Maintenance" whenever a new record is created in a list called "Issues". The new folder has a "name" of the Issue ID. The problem is the connected web parts don't allow me to link with the "name" column. How do i copy the folder name into another column as a next step in the flow. This will allow me to connect the web parts.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a “**Update file properties**” action under to update property for the folder. *Issue Id* is a **Number** column in the Maintenance library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to update a separate meta data column in the Library:

1. Assuming a column in the [Maintenance] Library already exists to store the item **Id** from the **Issue** list. In this example, it's [IssueID],  a **Number** type column.
2. Add **[Update item]** SharePoint action after [Create new folder]
3. For the List Name, select **Enter custom value** from the dropdown and then **type** in the Library name, **Maintenance**. Meta data column should be visible after the library information is refreshed.

Note: Action **[Create new folder]** returns the **Id** of the folder item after it gets created. Need to use the same Id to update the meta data column in the library.

### See the screenshots below

[image]

### Output:

[image]

Comment: The first ID of the update item section keeps coming up with an error "Enter a valid ID". The icons also aren't staying in the section it is converting it to "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1426/1.0.1426.2268/sharepointonline/icon.png"

Comment: Have you selected **Site Address** and **List Name** before selecting **ID** from the Dynamic Content? If those two are correct, I don't see any reason it would do that. However, you can try to add **outputs('Create_new_folder')?['body/ID']** in the expression window and save the flow, close it, and then again open for editing to see what happen. It's the same thing as selecting **ID** from the Dynamic content.

Comment: I placed     outputs('Create_new_folder')?['body/ID']     into the id field, closed and reopened and the icon was now there. What was i meant to type into the IssueID field? I drag and dropped the ID icon and it converted it to text again, however i could save and close this time. When i reopened the icon was now there. I tried running the flow, the outcome was it created folder Named 9 for issue 9, which is correct. However folder 9 didnt have anything in IssueID, what it did was change the IssueID of folder 4 to 16.

Comment: As I understood, you requirement didn't specify anything to be in the folder created in the **Maintenance** library. What do you expect in the folder? Please clarify or update the requirement in the original post.

Comment: Hi Matiur, I didn't need anything in the folder. I meant nothing appeared in the IssueID Column for that new folder. For some reason your method wouldn't work for me, I tried the suggestion below and it is working. Thanks for your help. Brett

Comment: Not seeing any logical difference in the 2nd solution. The only difference is that if [Title] is required in your case then it might not work. Anyway, glad to know that its working for you now.